# Cleanest way to provide an interface for a collection of dissimilar objects in C++

Tags: c++, class-hierarchy

I am quite new to C++, so I'm open to suggestions to improve my program architecture if I'm going about this the wrong way. This is a reasonably long question, so thanks for sticking with it!

I have several classes for various different sensors, and I would like to be able to present their data (light level, temperature, humidity etc, and possibly things other than sensors eventually) on a web page. The data is dynamic, so it needs to be fetched each time the page is loaded rather than passed statically to the web server. Ultimately the issue I'm facing is how to pass and store instances of different sensor objects in a generic way.

Thus far, I have a class that ultimately serves web pages, named `webServer`. The data sources for the `webServer` are instances of a `webData` class that are "registered" into the `webServer` and stored in a `std::map` so they can be individually addressed. A function with signature `std::string getValue(std::string key)` is called on each of these objects to provide strings for the web server to output.

The `webData` class is a pure abstract class acting as an interface, which the sensors all comply to. This works fine, though it does mean a bit of the web implementation has to "leak" into the sensor classes, but avoids having an adapter.

[image: Class Hierarchy]

I would like to pass a collection of sensors (and in the future, other non-sensor objects) to the `webServer` so it can access them individually by their type and ID. The above hierarchy falls down when there is a collection of sensors, and is where I'm not really sure how to proceed. I have a preexisting map of each type of sensor (humidity, temperature, etc), and to keep these types separate in the `webServer` class, I could have a map of maps - something like `map<string, map<string, webData*>*>`. I can then access the sensors with something like `sensorMap[“temperature”][“sensorName”]->getValue(key)`. A map of maps seems quite messy and unmaintainable however, and adding and removing sensors of a particular type would require specifically removing them from the webServer class as well as the preexisting map. I can't pass a pointer to the preexisting map of sensors because the map template is of type `humiditySensor` or `temperatureSensor`, not `webData`.

Perhaps it would be better to have a class for each sensor type that contains a collection of sensors, and conform that to an webCollection interface. This could be registered into the webServer. I could overload the [] operator within the sensor collection class to return webData pointers, and/or add iterator capabilities. Whilst this is ultimately a map of maps again, it keeps things a bit cleaner and more maintainable IMO.

[image: Collections Hierarchy]

I'm not really sure if I'm barking up the wrong tree here, entirely possible, or if I'm along the right lines. Thanks again for getting this far!

Edit: To clarify, I'd like to pass a collection of objects into the `webServer` such that each one can be individually called as required. The server might want data for a `temperatureSensor` with `sensorID` 6 for example, or in the future I'll probably want to be able to fetch a value from something that isn't a sensor. For example the state of a particular valve in a collection, which could return "opening, open, closing, closed" for example.

I can't pass a map of the sensor objects into the `webServer` because unless I have a map<string, sensor*>, I wouldn't be able to store it.

Comment: It looks like polymorphism would be in order.

Comment: just a thought... maybe you are overthinking it. Why do you need a generic way to pass the sensors data? You have a finite number of sensors and if their data has nothing in common then you won't gain much by pressing them in a common interface.

Comment: In modern web you'd have your web-server only serve the datasets using REST. The client browser would request the datasets and display them as necessary. No need to have all sensors in one collection. The client knows how to display different sensors and how to request them.

Comment: Why not implementing the storage in parent class when all derived classes share it (as temperature, sensorid, address) ?

Comment: @Ted's on the money. Make some abstract `Sensor` base class that has `double GetReding()`, `std::string GetReadingUnits()`, and `std::string GetSensorName()` functions. That should be all you'd want to do with a sensor, right?

Comment: @TedLyngmo that is what I was attempting with the webData interface - casting from the temperatureSensor class to the webData class. Then the webServer can access the data via getValue, and doesn't care what's underneath. I guess I wasn't polymorphic enough! :)

Comment: @scohe001 I think the `sensor` class would still have to be a subclass of `webData`, because in the future there may well be other non-sensor classes that I'd like to register into the `webServer`.

Comment: @idclev463035818 There will probably be non-sensor classes I'd like `webServer` to pull data from in the future, which was the reasoning behind the `webData` interface.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin that is very true, though I would still need to make the `webServer` aware of the data it needs to transmit, and preferably make it generic enough such that the `webServer` doesn't have to know anything about the data it is transmitting.

Comment: @dspr that is actually how it is implemented at the moment, I made a mistake in the diagram. Thanks though for pointing that out.

Comment: I think perhaps I have been a little unclear in one aspect I need - that's the ability to pass a collection of these sensor instances (and in the future - non sensor instances) to  `webServer` so that it can access them individually. I've edited to clarify.